# MS SQL arithmetic overflow after datetime comparison in where clause

Tags: t-sql, datetime, compare, sql-server-2014

i have a strange issue by using a date comparision on ms sql server 2014.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT AKTDET.*, DATEDIFF(day,aktdet.Bezahlt_am, getdate()- 50) as datumsdifferenz FROM (SELECT  Convert(datetime,AKTDET.von_num - 2.0,121) as [Bezahlt_am], AKT.KENNUNG, AKTDET.* FROM AKT INNER JOIN AKTDET ON AKT.DSN = AKTDET.AKT_DSN Inner JOin FLDART ON AKTDET.Fldart_Dsn = FLDART.DSN WHERE FLDART.Kürzel = 'bezahlt am') AS AKTDET ) AS AKTDET WHERE datumsdifferenz > 0.0
```

fails every time with "Arithmetischer Überlauffehler beim Konvertieren von expression in den datetime-Datentyp." translation: "Arithmetic overflow error when converting expression to datetime data type."

**if i don't use the where clause everything is fine. how could this happen?**

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT AKTDET.*, DATEDIFF(day,aktdet.Bezahlt_am, getdate()- 50) as datumsdifferenz FROM (SELECT  Convert(datetime,AKTDET.von_num - 2.0,121) as [Bezahlt_am], AKT.KENNUNG, AKTDET.* FROM AKT INNER JOIN AKTDET ON AKT.DSN = AKTDET.AKT_DSN Inner JOin FLDART ON AKTDET.Fldart_Dsn = FLDART.DSN WHERE FLDART.Kürzel = 'bezahlt am') AS AKTDET ) AS AKTDET
```

the data seems to be completely correct. all values are obiously correct date values.
here is a example of rows:

```
datumsdifferenz Bezahlt_am  KENNUNG     AKT_DSN
700 2016-12-21 00:00:00.000        340  690837DC-C521-47A7-B845-0B3036CADA07
391 2017-10-26 00:00:00.000       1887  27BC0276-0FAF-4787-BC69-4F7CC8F4D44A
391 2017-10-26 00:00:00.000       1887  27BC0276-0FAF-4787-BC69-4F7CC8F4D44A
392 2017-10-25 00:00:00.000       1890  102CA803-8EA7-48CB-95AE-AA2F8F686715
```

if i use 
`select top 80... WHERE datumsdifferenz > 0.0`
also everything will works fine.

if i use 
`select top 90... WHERE datumsdifferenz > 0.0`
it will throw again these strange error.

if i use a temp table and make the comparision after that it will work?!

Answer (score 1):

**i found the solution for myself. the query optimizier makes at first a whole table scan with convert, if i use where clause.**

the subquery with FLDART_DSN = (SELECT TOP 1 DSN FROM FLDART WHERE FLDART.Kürzel = 'bezahlt am') will be processed after the outer where clause. the whole table will be scanned in that situation. but the table contains data that are no date values. and that is the reason why the conversion will fail in that situation with outer where clause.

Solution:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT case When von_num < 90000.0 AND von_num > -400000.0 then convert(datetime,VON_NUM,104) END as bezahlt_am, *  FROM (SELECT  * FROM _TEST WHERE FLDART_DSN = (SELECT TOP 1 DSN FROM FLDART WHERE FLDART.Kürzel = 'bezahlt am')) as test) as test WHERE FLDART_DSN = (SELECT TOP 1 DSN FROM FLDART WHERE FLDART.Kürzel = 'bezahlt am') AND bezahlt_am  > GETDATE() - 100.0

SELECT convert(datetime,90000.0,104) -- 2146-05-31 00:00:00.000
SELECT convert(datetime,-40000.0,104) -- 1790-06-26 00:00:00.000
```